# Interpretation of geodesic departing angle

Tags: geometry, geodesic, ellipsoids, cartography

I'm trying to calculate the departing angle of a geodesic using several different methods in two different coordinate spaces.

Currently I'm testing the following geodesic terminal points:

- Start (80°W, 40°N)
- End (40°E, 21°N)

The two different coordinate spaces are:

- Earth-ellipsoidal (WGS-84, $a = 6,378,137$, $f = 0.0033528106647475126$)
- Earth-spherical ($a = 6,378,137$)

The methods are:

1. Plot the geodesic as a straight line in an orthographic projection (spherical only), and visually measure departing heading
2. Infinitesimal departure distance from start, use [`pyproj.Geod.inv_intermediate`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv_intermediate) to generate start portion of geodesic path, apply

$$
\tan^{-1} \frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$
That angle is clockwise from north and agrees very closely with method 1, producing 61.3° in the ellipsoidal and 61.5° in the spherical coordinate spaces respectively.

[image: screenshot]

Green is method 1 and red is method 2.

The following methods agree exactly with each other but not the methods above:

3. [`pyproj.Geod.inv()`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv), elliptical: 54.511°
4. `inv()` spherical: 54.600°
5. [Charles Karney's GeodSolve, elliptical](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve?type=I&input=40+-80+21+40&format=g&azi2=f&unroll=r&prec=3&radius=6378137&flattening=1%2F298.257223563&option=Submit): 54.511°
6. [GeodSolve, spherical](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve?type=I&input=40+-80+21+40&format=g&azi2=f&unroll=r&prec=3&radius=6378137&flattening=0&option=Submit): 54.600°

The GeodSolve method is described in [C. F. F. Karney, *Algorithms for geodesics*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z).

Intuitively I would think that every result should be close, but the gap between the arctan method and the others is too large. I would prefer to use `inv()`, but my current assumptions are that

- GeodSolve implementation is correct
- Both `pyproj` implementations are "correct", but produce different quantities that have each have a different geometric definition
- I've misunderstood what all of the theory is talking about when it describes departing angle

So what have I missed? How do I take the results from the second group of methods and match them up with the results of method 1?